# What is the significance of Mary treasuring and pondering in her heart?

Tags: exegesis, virgin-mary, gospel-of-luke

In "the Christmas parts" in Luke Mary's reaction to many great occurrences is to treasure and ponder them in her heart.

Is there specific significance to this phrasing or is it simply to highlight Mary's humility?

Comment: I asked the same question [on Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30068/what-is-the-significance-of-marys-contemplation-in-luke).

Comment: It is possible that Luke records the fact that Mary treasured and pondered over  these events because Mary was a primary source of information that Luke drew upon when writing his account of the life and death of Jesus.

Comment: I think this is a good question, just needs an "according to whom" to give you a good answer from a denominational perspective (if every priest and pastor in the world doesn't talk about this every advent, I'm not sure what they're doing). Otherwise, follow Sola Gratia's link for the textual meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose Luke got his information from Mary, and for her to have given them as though quoting them after many years proved she pondered and cherished those words, and was watching out for their fulfilment.